# how to restart dynamixel after overload error?

Tags: dynamixel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I'm using dynamixel_motor package to control my robot.

Often my dynamixel shows over load error because of tough usage. Once this error happans, I have to switch off my dynamixel and switch on again.

This way is not useful,so I would like to restart that dyanamixel through a program after over load error.

Could you tell me how to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239161/how-to-restart-dynamixel-after-overload-error?/) by [baozhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25430/baozhang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2016-07-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on the model of Dynamixel you are using. Some of the newer models (XM and Pro series) have reboot commands builtin. For the others it is a combination of toggling the torque enable register and setting the torque limit register http://forums.trossenrobotics.com/showthread.php?7289-How-to-clear-Dynamixel-Overload-error&p=66440#post66440.

Buggy behavior has also been noted in some AX-12 firmware releases, so the exact ordering of these steps may be different in some configurations http://forums.trossenrobotics.com/showthread.php?7289-How-to-clear-Dynamixel-Overload-error&p=66441#post66441.

Finally, if overload occurs it's usually a good idea to review your design and determine how it can be avoided. I've burnt up MOSFETs on several AX-12s by ignoring and resetting overload errors. At the very least be sure to let the motor cool down if the temperature is also high.

---

Originally posted by [penguin8](https://answers.ros.org/users/27453/penguin8/) with karma: 16 on 2016-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0